# Is there a difference between redirecting from a route guard and from the mounted() lifecycle hook inside a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Imagine there's a view which I only want to be accessible by logged in users. I can prevent the access by using a route guard on the route like this:

```
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (!store.getters.authenticated) {
            next({ name: "login" })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
```

But I was wondering if it'd be wrong if I used an if statement to determine if the user is logged in inside the mounted() lifecycle hook of the component I want to restrict.

```
mounted(){
    if(!store.getters.authenticated){
        router.push({name: "login"})
    }
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to the second method?

Comment: It just feels a little weird because it seems like you're doing things the router can do just fine but you're doing it inside of the component, so you're basically mixing the two. If you have a valid use case for the second method then /shrug

Comment: Browser use memory to load and run your component, so I don't think it's normal to do this in case then user are not authetificated.

Comment: @maxshuty There's actually a reason which is forcing me to look for alternative to route guard. Apparently, route guards are instantiated before the App.vue code, and my function which autoLogins the user is inside the App.vue. Because of that, isAuthenticated always returns false if I check for it inside the route guards, whereas it will return true if I check for it inside the component. I know this might not be the best way, but I can't figure out another way :\

Comment: You're using the Vuex store, why not auto login your user via the store so other components can check for authentication as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the router hook to trigger the authentication via the store.

Something like this:

```js
beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {

    await store.dispatch(`login`);

    if (!store.getters.authenticated) {
        next({ name: `login` });
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

And of course the automatic login logic in your component would have to be moved to your store's actions + mutations.